Requirements of TurtleBot2 (Ubuntu and ROS)
As per Installing Ubuntu 14.04 I can only use Ubuntu 14.04. Can I use any updated version of Ubuntu?
As per Installing ROS, I need to use ROS Indigo. Can I use any updated version?
